# Emulator fails with "Error connecting to the service protocol"

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am debugging flutter app from VS Code with Android emulator. I tried pixel 2 and 3. I use image 'Q'.

I am getting error:

> Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received

What can be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with image 'Q'. Image 'Pie' works well.